# PHP: Add words to pspell?

Tags: php, spell-checking, pspell

I am using pspell like this:

```
$ps = pspell_new("en");
if(!pspell_check($ps, $word))
{
    $suggestion = pspell_suggest($ps, $word);   
}
```

However I want to added some industry terms to the list.

I looked up `pspell_add_to_session` which says the first param is supposed to be `int $dictionary_link` But I do not know what that is and there is no example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the `$ps` variable created by `pspell_new()` is that "dictionary link":

```
$ps = pspell_new("en");
pspell_add_to_session($ps, "somenewword");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$dictionary_link` integer is an integer representation of the pspell library handle, as returned by [`pspell_new`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-new.php) or [`pspell_new_personal`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-new-personal.php). The PHP documentation is incomplete in a lot of places regarding this variable.<sup>[[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-config-personal.php)][[2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-config-save-repl.php)][[3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-config-mode.php)][[4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-config-ignore.php)][[5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-clear-session.php)][[6](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-check.php)][[7](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-add-to-session.php)][[8](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-add-to-personal.php)][[9](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-suggest.php)]</sup>